# Blank rows appearing when using ALLEXCEPT and number of days between entry and exit of a stock

Tags: powerbi

Below is my Dataset. I have created stock opening and stock closing columns excluding the movement types 311, 411, 415. But when i drag the fields into a table there seems to be **blank rows appearing which i would like to get rid off**.

The code that i have used is

Sum of Quantities = CALCULATE(SUM(Sheet1[Quantity]),FILTER(Sheet1,Sheet1[Movement type]<>311 && Sheet1[Movement type] <> 411 && Sheet1[Movement type] <> 415))

Opening Stock = CALCULATE([Sum of Quantities], FILTER(ALLEXCEPT(Sheet1,Sheet1[Material]),Sheet1[Entry Date]<MAX(Sheet1[Entry Date])))

Closing Stock = CALCULATE([Sum of Quantities], FILTER(ALLEXCEPT(Sheet1,Sheet1[Material]****),Sheet1[Entry Date]<=MAX(Sheet1[Entry Date])))

Additionally, I would like to find the number of days between entry (positive number) and exit (negative number) per sales order. But as you can see in the dataset a sales order is repeated and hence i am finding it difficult to find number of days between entry and exit.

[image: Dataset]

Error : Marked in red

[image]

Comment: Data in last 2 columns are correct?

Comment: Yes the data in the last 2 columns are correct (i.e. opening and closing stock)

Comment: Then showing row with NULL in first column is also logical. But you can filter out those rows if you really don't want to see them. Just apply filter on 1st column like >= 0

Comment: If i add a filter >= 0 then the negative values are also filtered. Which is destroying the result that i require

Comment: use not null that case.

Comment: I just found the solution. I filtered the Sum of quantities with the movement types that i do not require (i.e. 311, 411, 415). @mkRabbani thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter the Sum of quantities with the movement types that are not required (i.e. 311, 411, 415